# Probabilities using Z scores help

Tags: probability, statistics

How to calculate the probability of a z-transformed value does not appear in the table? e. g
What is the probability of randomly drawing a Z-transformed value of 2.465 or greater?
P(Z ≥ 2.46) = 0.0069 & P(Z ≥ 2.47) = 0.0068. it could be any value between 0.0068 and 0.0069???

b) What is P(|Z| ≥ z) = 0.07? it could between -1.81 and 1.81 if we split 0.07?

c)Suppose we have a population with μ=12, σ2=3 and Y~N(12,3).  What is 
P(Y ≥ 9.5)?

d)Suppose you have a population with μ=12, σ2=2 and Y~N(12,2).  What is 
P(Y ≤ -8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether we are dealing with a real-world question or a graded exercise.

For an exercise, you can **interpolate linearly** between $0.0069$ and $0.0068$. Since your point is halfway between $2.46$ and $2.47$, linear interpolation on the tabular values gives $0.00685$.

The situation is quite different if we are dealing not with gaps *between* table entries, but with numbers that go *beyond* the table. For many practical problems, it is enough to say that, for example, $\Pr(Z\gt 4)$ is negligible. But there are situations in which we do need more precise information. There are good formulas available for *estimating* the probability that $Z\gt z$, where $z$ is medium-sized, say in the range $3$ to $10$.

**Remark:** For a real-world application, it's not worth bothering. In a real world problem, we are using the normal distribution as an probabilistic model. Models and the real world are not the same thing. Many probabilistic models fit the real-world only modestly well. (A not very good model can still be useful.) So there is no point to trying for $3$ significant digit accuracy. Anyway, modern software can get you much greater precision than that.